# CMake doesn't generate vc pdb for simple test program

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, cmake

I am trying to use CMake on Windows 10. I create a Hello world project:

> CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

add_executable(simple-program main.cpp)
```

> main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
}
```

Then I open the project with CMake gui, choose `Visual Studio 10 2010 Win64` generator and get this error when trying to generate the project:

```
testCCompiler.c : fatal error C1033: cannot open program database 'c:\work\prj\simple-program\build\cmakefiles\cmaketmp\cmtc_983e7.dir\debug\vc100.pdb'
```

[Full output](https://pastebin.com/jFqGZQL4).

As I understood the problem, due to `Zi` option and no `Fd`, which cmake sets for the sample project, the project is trying to find `vc100.pdb` database and there is no one because the generator didn't make it.

I've tried the x86 generator. Other cmake versions (3.6, 3.13, 3.12). And I get the same result when using the console. My VS 2010 should be ok - it generates the PDB when I create the project from it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was because I created build folder in [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) console. So it can be caused by any kind emulators like Cygwin, etc. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1033?view=vs-2017

Fatal Error C1033

This error can be caused by a disk error, a temporary lock created by an anti-virus program, a previous debugger instance that has not fully shut down, or parallel build mspdbsrv.exe processes that attempt to access the same file, among other possible causes.

NOTE:
I couldn't find the error codes for VS2010 on the Microsoft website.  I don't think VS2010 is supported anymore and may not make working programs on Windows 10.

Comment: I think I should try to run cmake gui as adminitrator. I will have a chance to try it at Monday. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. I don't have an anti-virus. And there should be no debugger instances, because I restarted the system.

Answer (score -2):

Just build your generated project in Debug mode:

```
MSBuild ALL_BUILD.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug
```

If you want to create a Release and install it with PDB files just all:

```
list(APPEND INSTALL_TARGETS simple-program)
list(APPEND INSTALL_TARGETS_PDB simple-program)

# Install
install(TARGETS ${INSTALL_TARGETS}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin"
  LIBRARY DESTINATION "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin"
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")

# Install *.pdb files
if(MSVC)
  foreach(INSTALL_TARGET_PDB ${INSTALL_TARGETS_PDB})
    install(FILES $<TARGET_PDB_FILE:${INSTALL_TARGET_PDB}> DESTINATION "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")
  endforeach()
endif()
```

Finall run CMake and build in `RelWithDebInfo` mode:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 10 2010 Win64"
MSBuild ALL_BUILD.vcxproj /p:Configuration=RelWithDebInfo
MSBuild INSTALL.vcxproj /p:Configuration=RelWithDebInfo
```

This will create `simple-program.exe` and `simple-program.pdb` files in your install dir.

Comment: I think it is supposed to build the simple test program without any pdb install.

Comment: @NuPagadi, MSBuild ALL_BUILD.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Dedug - will be enough for this case

Comment: It fails on `cmake -G "Visual Studio 10 2010 Win64"`: `cannot open program database`.